# Двойной вызов функции Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Подскажите, почему при клике на кнопку, функция вызывается два раза?
Как сделать, что бы она вызывалась один раз?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      loader: null,
      loading: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    loader() {
      const l = this.loader
      this[l] = !this[l]

      setTimeout(() => (this[l] = false), 3000)
      this.qwerty();
      this.loader = null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    qwerty() {
      console.log('double');
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.btn_text {
  color: black;
}

.LoaderBtn {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-modal>
    <v-btn class="LoaderBtn" :loading="loading" :disabled="loading" color="primary" @click="loader = 'loading'">
      <span class="btn_text">
      Accept Terms
    </span>
    </v-btn>
  </v-modal>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, в самом watch есть изменение переменной, за которой он наблюдает

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      loader: null,
      loading: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    loader() {
      const l = this.loader
      this[l] = !this[l]

      setTimeout(() => (this[l] = false), 3000)
      this.qwerty();
     
    }
  },
  methods: {
    qwerty() {
      console.log('double');
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.btn_text {
  color: black;
}

.LoaderBtn {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-modal>
    <v-btn class="LoaderBtn" :loading="loading" :disabled="loading" color="primary" @click="loader = 'loading'">
      <span class="btn_text">
      Accept Terms
    </span>
    </v-btn>
  </v-modal>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```